# is there a problem with the way I set up factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm following micheal hartl rails tutorial. I'm on chapter 10. is there something wrong with the way I've define the cotent part in factory girl .
I'm getting this error from factory girl when I'm calling rspec .

```
Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: @user, created_at: 1.day.ago)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `content=' for #<User:0x0000010343f018>
```

**factories.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)    { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email)   { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com" }
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end

    factory :micropost do 
       content "Lorem ipsum "
       #association :user
       user
    end
  end 
end
```

**the part that's been called**

```
 before { @user.save }
    let!(:older_micropost ) do 
      FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: @user, created_at: 1.day.ago)
    end
    let!(:newer_micropost) do
      FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: @user, created_at: 1.hour.ago)
    end
    it " should  have  the right  micropost in the right  order" do 
      @user.microposts.should == [newer_micropost, older_micropost]
    end
```

Comment: Can you confirm you've run `rake db:test:prepare`? it might need to be run to add the "content" column to the microsposts table.

Comment: yes i do finally got it working thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `factory :micropost` out of `factory :user`, otherwise it will consider the `content` as an attribute of user.

This should work:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)    { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email)   { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com" }
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end 

  factory :micropost do 
    content "Lorem ipsum "
    association :user
  end

end
```